# FullCalendar not showing after screen width less than or equal to 767px

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

```js
var initialLocaleCode = 'en'
var localeSelectorEl = document.getElementById('locale-selector');
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
let calender_data = []

calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
  expandRows: true,
  height: 'auto',
  stickyHeaderDates: true,
  headerToolbar: {
    left: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'prevYear,prev,next,nextYear'
  },

  locale: initialLocaleCode,
  direction: 'rtl',
  buttonIcons: false, // show the prev/next text
  navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
  editable: true,
  dayMaxEvents: true, // allow "more" link when too many events

  eventDidMount: function(info) {
    $(info.el).tooltip({
      title: info.event.extendedProps.description,
      placement: "top",
      trigger: "hover",
      container: "body"
    });
  },

  events: function(info, successCallback, failureCallback) {
    successCallback(calender_data);
  },
});

calendar.render();

// build the locale selector's options
calendar.getAvailableLocaleCodes().forEach(function(localeCode) {
  var optionEl = document.createElement('option');
  optionEl.value = localeCode;
  optionEl.selected = localeCode == initialLocaleCode;
  optionEl.innerText = localeCode;
  localeSelectorEl.appendChild(optionEl);
});

// when the selected option changes, dynamically change the calendar option
localeSelectorEl.addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (this.value) {
    calendar.setOption('locale', this.value);
  }
});
```

```css
.fc-header-toolbar {
  margin-right: 2em;
  margin-left: 2em;
}

.fc-header-toolbar .fc-toolbar-chunk .fc-toolbar-title {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 600;
  border: 0.1em solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-left: 0.3em;
  padding-top: 0.1em;
  padding-bottom: 0.1em;
  padding-right: 0.3em;
}

@media (max-width: 573px) {
  .fc .fc-toolbar.fc-header-toolbar {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .fc-header-toolbar .fc-toolbar-chunk {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
  }
  .fc-header-toolbar .fc-toolbar-chunk .fc-toolbar-title {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 600;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.10.1/main.css">


<div class="container px-5 py-5 mt-3 collapse mb-3" id="add-event-container">

  <div class="row g-0 gx-3 justify-content-center" id="calender-add-event-row">

    <div class="col-sm-3 grid">
      <label for="toDate">To</label>
      <input type="date" class="add-event-input" id="toDate">
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3 grid">
      <label for="fromDate">From</label>
      <input type="date" class="add-event-input" placeholder="Enter from date" id="fromDate">
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="row g-0 gx-5 gy-2 justify-content-center mt-3" id="calender-add-event-row">

    <div class="col-sm-3 grid">
      <label for="locale-selector">Locales</label>
      <select id='locale-selector' class="add-event-input" style="border: 0.1em solid rgb(199, 199, 199); border-radius: 3px;"></select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3 grid">
      <label for="eventName">Event Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="add-event-input" placeholder="Enter event" id="eventName">
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3 grid">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="addEvent">Add</button>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<div id='calendar' class="mb-5"></div>



<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.10.1/main.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.10.1/locales-all.min.js"></script>
```

I dont know why its showing in the `Run Snippet`. Also I cant reproduce the full code because there are many functions after which the calender is rendered. But if the screen width <= 767px the calender will not show. I also cant pinpoint to any problem because the console shows no error which you  can see from the screenshots below.

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you inspect the styles for the `<div id='calendar' class="mb-5"></div>`, where is it getting it's height from when the page is smaller than 767px width? The toolbar appears to be showing, but not the calendar underneath, so perhaps it has a small height set in CSS somewhere.

Comment: Yes, I thought of that but when view the inspect elements column on the browser whilie reducing the size of the screen width nothing changes dynamically that can do this. The height of the calender is set as `auto` which you can see in the above code.

Comment: We need a [mre] of the issue. You've posted a snippet which doesn't demonstrate the problem, so we can't use it to help you. You need to go through your code and add other things from your real code into the snippet until you encounter the problem again. That should narrow down the issue, both for us and for you. Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson the problem is solved. I have a page where there are many tables. I changes the styling of that tables when the screen width becomes less than 767px. That was causing the problem.